# ASP.Net / IIS redirect all old domain pages to new domain homepage using

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

I want to 301 redirect all old domain pages to a new domain home page.

e.g.

```
olddomain.com -> newdomain.com
olddomain.com/page -> newdomain.com
```

If i set in web config:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newdomain.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
```

olddomain.com/page redirects to newdomain.com/page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use `exactDestination="true"`